# Total timeout of API google.datastore.v1.Datastore exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, grpc, datastore

Facing issue with GCP datastore While querying to get value from the datastore. The request query took more time and threw an error: **TimeOut Exceeded **

**RunnTime Environment**
Nodejs: ^16

**Package**
@google-cloud/datastore: ^7.5.1

**Error**
Total timeout of API google.datastore.v1.Datastore exceeded 60000 milliseconds before any response was received.
at repeat (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/retries.js:66:31)

Can someone help me on fixing this.

Comment: In order to help you, we will need to see your code, how you're authenticating to Google Cloud and a synopsis of what you did to create the Firestore|Datastore database.